# What will be the AWS API Gateway Resource policy structure, if someone invoking it from GCP (api gateway)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-api-gateway, google-cloud-api-gateway, google-api-gateway

So I have an AWS API Gateway running.  An api call (I believe from API gateway, GCP) need to invoke my AWS API.  So I want to know what is the structure of AWS API Gateway resource policy.  So that I can restrict access to allow traffic only from the GCP.

Unfortunately, i didn't find any source to try this